# mysql . updates duplicates values with values from similar row

Tags: mysql

I got a tables with duplicates values.  I need to update values in rows by copying from another row.

The table has over 120K rows.

For example, the `products` table has this data:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| products_model  |    products_ean | products_image       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 43853103        |   344534534544  | product_noimage.gif  |
| 2145B001        |   376766767777  | 798368_1019.jpg      |
| 44544545        |   344343344355  | eee_fee.jpg          |
| 43853103        |   344534534544  | 43853103_sed.jpg     |
| 2145B001        |   376766767777  | product_noimage.gif  |
| 4567878344      |                 | 4567878344_hhg.jpg   |
| 4567878344      |                 | product_noimage.gif  |
```

I want to search  all records with a certain criteria.  For example, for all products where `products_model` is `43853103` and `ean_number` is `344534534544`, then update `product_image` as `43853103_sed.jpg`.  So in the above example `product_noimage.gif` is replaced with `43853103_sed.jpg` for all  products where `products_model` is `43853103` and `ean_number` is `344534534544`.

For single records it is easy to update.

I would like to search the whole product table for duplicates and update the product_image field  using product_model and ean_number as the matching criteria.

I only want the update  to happen where the ean_number  is not  empty. So product_model like 4567878344 should not update.

kind regards

Comment: you only want to update the ean_number which is present. and what u have to update in it?

Comment: i have updated my question . i only want t to update the product_image field

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an update join here:

```
UPDATE products p1
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT
         products_model,
         MAX(CASE WHEN products_image <> 'product_noimage.gif'
                  THEN products_image END) AS products_image
     FROM products
     GROUP BY products_model
     HAVING COUNT(products_ean) > 1
 ) p2
     ON p1.products_model = p2.products_model
SET p1.products_image = p2.products_image;
```

Comment: i have over 100K models and i need it to find and updates  values as listed above.. how can i find it by using update

Comment: @naf I have answered the exact question you posed.  If you need some other update, then edit your question and state the logic.

Comment: i have updated my question .. to make it clearer.. what i want trying to do

Comment: @naf I also updated my answer to match your actual logic.